# Flutter-Headphone Recognition

Tags: flutter

I'm developing a TikTok/Reels type application and the app is currently detecting sound from the phone mic only. Can anyone help in enabling detection from headphones(wire/wireless) if being used?
Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can use https://pub.dev/packages/headset_connection_event

Code from the plugin page:

```
    import 'package:headset_connection_event/headset_event.dart';

    // Instantiate it
    HeadsetEvent headsetPlugin = new HeadsetEvent();
    HeadsetState headsetEvent;

    /// if headset is plugged
    headsetPlugin.getCurrentState.then((_val){
      setState(() {
        headsetEvent = _val;
      });
    });

    /// Detect the moment headset is plugged or unplugged
    headsetPlugin.setListener((_val) {
      setState(() {
        headsetEvent = _val;
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Karim. Appreciate it.